# Add log to destination object when using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is it possible to add a log to the destination object, when using AutoMapper?

If I have two objects:

```
class A
{
    int PropertyOne
    int PropertyTwo
    int PropertyThree
    List<string> Log
}

class B
{
    int PropertyOne
    int PropertyTwo
}
```

When mapping from B to A, I'd like to automatically have a log entry added to A.Log for every property that is changed.

E.g. if during a mapping operation, PropertyOne = 3 on both objects, but A.PropertyTwo = 1 and B.PropertyTwo = 2, I'd like to have a log entry added to A.Log - preferably something like "PropertyTwo changed from 1 to 2"

Comment: `Automapper` isn't  a logging framework.

Comment: Touche! ;-) However I'd just like to piggyback a little bit on its functionality ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an auto-property, create a property with a *custom* setter in which you add an entry to the log list.

Example console application:

```
public static class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        private int _PropertyOne;
        private int _PropertyTwo;
        private int _PropertyThree;

        public int PropertyOne
        {
            get { return _PropertyOne; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _PropertyOne)
                    return;

                Log.Add(string.Format("PropertyOne changing value from {0} to {1}", _PropertyOne, value));
                _PropertyOne = value;
            }
        }

        public int PropertyTwo
        {
            get { return _PropertyTwo; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _PropertyTwo)
                    return;

                Log.Add(string.Format("PropertyOne changing value from {0} to {1}", _PropertyTwo, value));
                _PropertyTwo = value;
            }
        }

        public int PropertyThree
        {
            get { return _PropertyThree; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _PropertyThree)
                    return;

                Log.Add(string.Format("PropertyOne changing value from {0} to {1}", _PropertyThree, value));
                _PropertyThree = value;
            }
        }

        public List<string> Log { get; private set; }

        public A()
        {
            Log = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
        public int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<A, B>().ReverseMap();
        });

        var b = new B() {PropertyOne = 1, PropertyTwo = 2};
        var a = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<B, A>(b);

        a.Log.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
    }
}
```

This will output:

> PropertyOne changing value from 0 to 1
>
> PropertyTwo changing value from 0 to 2

Comment: Is there no way to have AutoMapper do this? I'd like to keep all the boiler plate code out the the property setters, as I'll have many different objects, and only want to log changes, if done by AutoMapper (and would very much like to avoid having to implement a "IsLoggingEnabled" flag to control when logging should be enabled or not).

Comment: You could add it in the Mapper (formember, forallmembers in the CreatMap), but it is not neat at all (AutoMapper is not a logging utility).

Comment: You can also play around with PostSharp (https://www.postsharp.net/) to reduce boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) that would work with a marker interface called `IPropertyLogger`. Any subtype of that could be explicitly used by `AutoMapper`.

The type converter could use reflection and perform the diff-like operation you are requesting before calling default AutoMapper behavior. This would work for all tagged types and you would not have to code each object specifically for the case.

Your reflection based diff code would handle all of the logging you require keeping you objects clean from implementation code.